# How can I convert an HTML table to a CSV file, while taking colspan and rowspan into account?

Tags: html, perl, csv

I have a Perl module that constructs an HTML table within it. I need to add a button that allows me to save this table as a CSV file.

I can figure out how to do that much of it, but I'm having some problems with formatting, namely when it comes to `colspan` and `rowspan` tags. This is causing everything to shift and mess up since it thinks there are empty columns.

Is there away to handle the `colspan` and `rowspan` tags while converting this table to a CSV, so that the formatting stays consistent?

Comment: Please add sample HTML input along with the resulting CSV output.

Comment: I seem to recall begin able to copy and paste an HTML table into a Excel.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *"within it"* in *"I have a Perl module that constructs an HTML table within it"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you showed an example of the data that is causing you poblems then we could help you better, but the [`HTML::TableExtract`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTableExtract) module takes account of `rowspan` and `colspan` issues, and can be used to generate CSV data.

However it seems best to write your Perl so that the code is driven by a data source so that it can produce *either* HTML *or* CSV data. It is wrong to scan the HTML that you have produced to regenerate the original data source, and create CSV-formatted output from that